# Split String and Summarise Values into Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table full of strings that look like the following: `P12D1P13D1P2D47R1D37P3D1R10D10`

What would be the best way to split the string by P, D and R and then SUM per each letter group?

For example summarised as columns:

| P | D | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 97 | 11 |

Comment: Is fixing your data *before* it gets anywhere near SQL Server an option? If not, it really should be.

Comment: How many different letter groups are there?

Comment: Is it always just PDR? Or any single letters

Comment: I *assume* you are also limited to only those 3 letters as well?

Comment: 3 different people asking the same comment in 15 seconds tells you just how important that information is. :)

Comment: Think of the letters as "tokens" to split on then sum the values between tokens for each token group.  Use the split function to get rows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: String parsing can be done in SQL but C# or another programming language is much more suited for it and much faster.   If you cant fix the data before you get it, you can build CLR function (a C# function you import into SQL) that you can design to do exactly what you want.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419909/is-a-question-asking-for-good-ways-to-do-something-really-opinion-based

Comment: It is limited to a fix amount of letters; P, D, R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using CROSS APPLY and string_split() and a conditional aggregation

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (id int,[SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'P12D1P13D1P2D47R1D37P3D1R10D10')
 
Select A.id
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (replace(replace(replace(SomeCol,'P','|P'),'D','|D'),'R','|R'))) B(S)
 Cross Apply ( Select D = sum(case when Item='D' then Val end)
                     ,P = sum(case when Item='P' then Val end)
                     ,R = sum(case when Item='R' then Val end)
                From  string_split(S,'|')  C1
                Cross Apply (values (left(value,1),try_convert(int,substring(value,2,25)))) C2(Item,Val)
             ) C
```

**Results**

```
id  D   P   R
1   97  30  11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` to add a `,` before each string token. Then use `STRING_SPLIT` to split them up, and `SUBSTRING` to get the number part (which you can convert using `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT`).

Put all that into a subquery and use conditional `SUM`

```sql
SELECT
  t.*,
  s.*
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      SUM(TRY_CAST(CASE WHEN s.value LIKE 'P%' THEN SUBSTRING(s.value, 2, LEN(s.value) - 1) END AS int)) AS P,
      SUM(TRY_CAST(CASE WHEN s.value LIKE 'D%' THEN SUBSTRING(s.value, 2, LEN(s.value) - 1) END AS int)) AS D,
      SUM(TRY_CAST(CASE WHEN s.value LIKE 'R%' THEN SUBSTRING(s.value, 2, LEN(s.value) - 1) END AS int)) AS R
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(
      REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            t.BadData,
            'P', ',P'
          ),
          'D', ',D'
        ),
        'R', ',R'
      ), ',') s
      WHERE s.value <> ''
) s
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/uNkqujAQ)